# Is it possible to use two different schemas in same form using yup and react-hook-forms?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I have a basic form that has two inputs `input1` and `input2`. In the first schema both fields are required but in the second schema, only the first field is required.I have two buttons on the same form. Is it possible to trigger first validation schema when pressing `button1` an second on pressing `button2`? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

```
const schema1 = yup.object().shape({
              input1: yup.string().email().required(),
              input2: yup.string().min(4).max(20).required(),
              });
const schema2 = yup.object().shape({
              input1: yup.string().email().required(),
              input2: yup.string().min(4).max(20),
              });
```

The form is similar to this:

```
const {handleSubmit} = useFormContext();

<form onSubmit= {handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
       <input name="input1" /> 
       <input name="input2" />  

       <button type="submit">button1</button>
       <button type="submit">button2</button>
</form>
```